# Robot_localization - GPS heading problem

Tags: ros2, robot-localization, gps, navsat-transform-node, ekf-localization-node

I hope someone can help me

I'm using robot_localization to improve my location estimation using the following ekf nodes

- ekf_node_odom: odometry + IMU
- ekf_node_map: odometry + IMU + GPS

the first node ekf_node_odom fusion odometry and IMU smoothly, below the image.

- green: raw odometry of my vehicle
- red: odometry ekf_node_odom
  (odometry + IMU)
  [image]

the second node however gives me problems regarding orientation, when the ekf_node_map starts, the GPS data (blue) has a different heading, from rviz you can see how the global odometry (odometry + IMU + GPS) initially follows a different path from the GPS one, this seems to dirty the global odometry a lot.

- blue: GPS odometry purple: odometry
- ekf_node_map (odometry + IMU +
  GPS)
  [image]
  [image]

Is it linked to the parameters of the navsat_transform node?
Can anyone tell me how to adjust the parameters for my location? (Milan - Italy)

```
navsat_transform:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    delay: 3.0
    magnetic_declination_radians: 0.0580707 #it is right for milan - italy?
    yaw_offset: 0.0
    zero_altitude: true
    broadcast_utm_transform: true
    publish_filtered_gps: true
    use_odometry_yaw: true
    wait_for_datum: false
```

Comment: Please include your full EKF config and a sample message from all sensor inputs.